# Run Boost unit test with my own main function for debugging

Tags: unit-testing, boost, boost-test

I have a library inside which there are some testing programs written using `Boost.Test`. The test files don't have `#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK` or `#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>`. They only have `#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>`. So the `main()` function isn't there implicitly.

Now I have to debug some library functions which have been used in the test cases. Given that I **cannot** add or change anything in the test programs, how can I invoke the test programs under a debugger ?

Comment: If you can't add anything, then how would you add your own `main()`? You say "programs" which would imply there's an executable produced. So just run them in the debugger like any other executable (you didn't specify platform or toolkit, so I can't give you any more detail on that). | At this point, the question is rather confusing, please elaborate more.

Comment: Sorry, by programs I meant files (CPP files) and I am not allowed to change those CPP files in anyway.
There is no executable. But I can create new files and compile them to generate executable and that is exactly my question, how can I do that ?
Btw, I'm using QtCreator as IDE, g++4.8 on ubuntu.

Comment: The framework seems to be used [as static library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html#boost_test.usage_variants.static_lib) - so just follow those instructions to make the test runner.

Answer (score 0):

Create a test runner (e.g. `main_test.cpp`) and link your library against that.

```
# main_test.cpp
// --- Boost Includes ---
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

Invoking the resulting executable should run your tests. You can then debug individual tests by invoking the runner with `./myrunner --run_test='some_testsuite'/../'some_testname'`.